# Tkinter application freezes with high number of entry/text fields

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a small program where I want to edit a big size table. See the example program below.

```
from tkinter import *


def table_generator(root):
    size = 10
    table_frame = Frame(root)
    for i in range(size):  # Rows
        for j in range(size):  # Columns
            b = Text(table_frame, width=2, height=1)
            b.grid(row=i, column=j)
    table_frame.pack(side="left", anchor="nw")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = Tk()
    table_generator(application)
    mainloop()
```

This works as I intended, but when I increase my size to 40, the program is slow to start and freezes if I try to move it. However, I want to increase this to around 200 at some point.

Does any of you have an alternative for this? I want to be able to enter a single character and change the background color in the end. Or some way of coding so that it does work with high numbers of Entry of Text fields?

Thanks

Comment: Simulate does not allow you to use both pack and grid. https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-grid/

Comment: I'm using grid within the frame and pack for the frame itself. This works normally, and as expected. Or do you mean that that could explain the freezing issue?

Comment: It is not freezing. So you cannot used pack()

Comment: Did you try with a higher size also? Because with 40 it did feel like a small increase in perfomance if I use grid only, but with 100 it's still freezing

Comment: Yes. When I click the edge of the window to resize. The size doesn't matter.

Comment: Weird, for me it's still freezing and eventually crashing when I use size=100, even with grid only

Comment: @toyotaSupra: you can use both `pack` and `grid` as long as you don't use them together on widgets with the same parent. In this case it's OK since the text widgets and `table_frame` have different parents.